# Are those components mandatory?

Tags: schematics, design, emi-filtering, nfc

I am building this circuit for an NFC component ST25R95 on a small PCB.

I am wondering if I can disregard the marked components on the power supply (inductors and capacitors for filtering.) These components were not mentioned in the datasheet but I recently found that they were in the evaluation board design of the component.

Is it necessary to place them or not?

[ST25R95 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/st25r95.pdf)

[Module datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/ecosystems/stm32-open-development-environment/stm32-nucleo-expansion-boards/stm32-ode-connect-hw/x-nucleo-nfc03a1.html#documentation)

[image]

Comment: Weigh up the risk - if you don’t put the extra components in and you have problems then what is your Plan B? This device is a RF transmitter so you need to be careful that only the wanted parts of your circuit radiate and not the power tracks. You also want the incoming supply to be ‘quiet’ for best read performance. I experienced a problem where the output cap on a switcher feeding the rfid chip was marginal. Read range would decrease over time or be bad from the outset. Heat the cap and magically it worked again. Drove me crazy until i realised what was happening.

Comment: It is better to have it on the PCB and not populate it, than wonder if it might have an effect on some problem and not have it.  If you circuit is close to power source and it has a large capacitor, a small cap on input may be all that you need.  The inductors are there to filter any regulator ripple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Probably not.

If the 3.3V supply is especially noisy (especially at frequencies of interest i.e. low 10s MHz), even more filtering may be desirable.  Offhand, I doubt that much is needed in typical cases (e.g. 3.3V switching regulator, well bypassed supplies, ~mV ripple/noise).  NFC also isn't a particularly wide dynamic range application, mind I haven't exactly designed a receiver myself, but I would assume it's far from what a general purpose radio receiver would be capable of.

In case filtering is required, after all, I would recommend against ferrite beads, anyway.  They saturate easily with DC bias current -- probably not enough to matter here (saturation is typically 10s to 100s of mA), but something to keep in mind for general power supply filtering purposes.  Saturation means the element's impedance drops as DC bias current goes up, thus reducing attenuation and raising the cutoff frequency.

I also recommend against the staggered capacitor values in parallel.  This can have the opposite effect, particularly at frequencies relevant here.  For example, a 10nF 0402 (approx. 2nH ESL) in parallel with a 100nF 0603 (approx. 3nH) gives an equivalent parallel resonant circuit of 9.1nF and 5nH, or Fo = 23.6MHz and Zo = 0.23Ω.  For X7R type capacitors, this will have a Q factor around 5 or so, giving a parallel resonant peak around 1.1Ω at 23.6 ± 4.7 MHz.  If the capacitors aren't perfectly butted together, and the capacitances are lower due to various effects*, the stray inductance of the connecting traces can easily drop that to 13.56MHz, where the supply impedance will suddenly be much higher than intended, perhaps leading to malfunction.

Best practice is generally to just use the largest capacitance, in the smallest chip size acceptable for the project, placed at the pin(s) that need it.  Then connect to a bulk capacitor, meaning a relatively large value (at least 3 times the first cap) and having modest ESR (usually electrolytic or tantalum, but can be polymer -- shop around for suitable ESR, they are available in a range of values -- or ceramic in series with a small resistor).  Often this is on the supply rail itself, but particularly when isolated from that rail with a filter inductor, a local bulk cap will be required.  This ESR sets the minimum supply impedance the chip will see.

*Type 2 (X7R, etc.) dielectric experiences loss of capacitance due to three effects: temperature, bias voltage, and aging.  Temperature is simply within the tolerance specified, so, 10% up to 125°C, not bad; it drops precipitously above there, though.  (It also 'freezes out' at low temperatures i.e. < -55°C.)  Voltage depends on chip size and manufacture; the best way to tell is to find the characteristic sheet for the part chosen, and find C loss under bias.  (Probably, this will be quite minor for a 10nF at 3.3V, even in 0402 size, probably even in 0201 size -- but you only know for sure with these data.  *The rated voltage has no relation to the C(V) curve, and large values can be -80% or worse at ratings!*  Finally, aging reduces the value slowly over time, with loss falling roughly as log(t).  So maybe it's -5% in the first week, another -5% in three months, -5% in a few years...  It's not much, but it adds up particularly for old equipment.  Aging is reset by annealing (heating above curie temperature), which occurs during soldering.

Comment: Tim Williams thank you for your detailed answer. These informations were very useful to know.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the 'lore' about paralleled close capacitors.  1uF is also pretty small bulk for a bulk capacitor---probably fine here, but electrolytics are cheap and this doesn't sound like a large run.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what the end usage is and the long term requirements including environmental. I have come across designers that keep removing parts and when the thing quits working the put the last part back and go from there. To determine if the part is needed the design should go through the appropriate design process including the FMEA (Failure Mode Effect Analysis). You also have to keep in mind what the target is. If it is for example an ABS controller or a blinking candle, the requirements are drastically different. The manufacturer does not know the end usage of the part so they normally assume worst case, this does cause them to add "extra parts". There are ramifications if the pard does not do what they say it will do. There is a difference between hobby and production.