# Output capacitor for an LM2950 3.3 V regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I’m looking to understand what the best output capacitance is to use for my [LM2950](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lp2950-d.pdf) 3.3V regulator. In the datasheet it is specified to be 1uF. What would be the effect if I use a smaller capacitor?  Say, for example, 100nF.

Comment: This is effectively a decoupling question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639189/placing-of-capacitor-close-to-ic-power-pin-logic/639191#639191 is probably a useful link. Without knowing your schematic and layout the simple rules are: more capaticance means smoother power rails.

Comment: The datasheet says: *Need only 1uF for stability*. With less it may be unstable, oscillate, and destroy your load.

Answer (score 2):

The [datasheet of the LM2950](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lp2950-d.pdf) goes into some detail.

The short version is that 1µF or more is needed to guarantee stability under normal operating conditions.  That is to say, to keep the output from oscillating.

If you have a light load, you can get away with a smaller output capacitor.

Page 9 gives the details:

> These regulators are not internally compensated and thus require a 1.0 F (or greater) capacitance between the LP2950/LP2951 output terminal and ground for stability. Most types of aluminum, tantalum or multilayer ceramic
> will perform adequately. Solid tantalums or appropriate multilayer ceramic capacitors are recommended for operation below 25°C.
>
> At lower values of output current, less output capacitance is required for output stability. The capacitor can be reduced to 0.33 µF for currents less than 10 mA, or 0.1 µF for currents below 1.0 mA. Using the 8 pin versions at voltages less than 5.0 V operates the error amplifier at lower values of gain, so that more output capacitance is needed for stability. For the
> worst case operating condition of a 100 mA load at 1.23 V output (output Pin 1 connected to the feedback Pin 7) a minimum capacitance of 3.3 µF is recommended.

Take a look at the operating conditions (input voltage, output voltage, load current, and chip version) then decide if you need more than the recommended 1µF or if you can get away with less than 1µF.

---

An oscillating voltage regulator can get quite hot.  It may even destroy itself and the circuit it is supposed to providing power to.

When selecting the output capacitor, it is better to err on the safe side - too large rather than too small a capacitor.